# How to generate email on failed test cases in selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Unable to generate email on Failed test cases in selenium web driver, have generated the generic email(on Passed/Failed Test cases) and it will send an email at the end of the test suite in TestNG framework but the requirement here is to send an email only in the case  of failed test case(s).

Here is the code snippet of Email:

```
    String to="smimran@macrosoftinc.com";
          final String username = "username";
          final String password = "password";

          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
              }
          });

          try {

              Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
              message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("syed.imran3411@gmail.com"));
              message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                  InternetAddress.parse(to));
              message.setSubject("A testing mail header !!!");
              message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                  + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");


              MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

              Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

              messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
              String file = "F:\\Java Selenium\\WorkPlace\\Velco Automation Testing\\test-output\testng.css";
              String fileName = "testng.css";
              DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
              messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
              messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
              multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

              Thread.sleep(5000);

              message.setContent(multipart);

              Transport.send(message);

              System.out.println("Done");
}
}
```

Please suggest me the solution. Thanks!

Comment: are you using testng listeners

Comment: You don't want to do this. You need to send mail whether there are failed tests or not. What if there are no failures? You never get an email. Consider this... if you don't get an email, are your tests done and everything passed or are the tests still running? You don't know unless you send the email no matter what.

Comment: No, not using listeners and yes want to send email only in case of any test case failed else not send email for passed test cases!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Jenkins and send mail via the [email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).